# iOS App rejected - Your promotional image is the same as your app’s icon

Tags: ios, metadata

I am just confused where am i supposed to add this promotional image. Like when i am submitting the app on iTunes connect or somewhere else?

Comment: Is this in Xcode 9/newest? In that version there is a 1024x1024 “marketing” icon

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: The screenshots of your app cannot just be your icon. They must be the screenshots of the actual app itself OR images that showcase your app (photoshop, gimp, illustrator, etc can be used to create these)..